# Django Version 1.8.3 SQL Server v13 is not supported

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm new to this stuff so I apologize if this is in the wrong place. I've inherited a Debian 7.14 system that has Django version 1.8.3 and Python version 2.7.6. It has a connection to SQL Server. We've just upgraded to SQL Server 2016 and are now getting the error

Exception Type: NotImplementedError
Exception Value: Sql Server v13 is not supported.

How can I upgrade to a newer version of Django for this connection to work again? What version will work with SQL Server 2016? I'm thinking it would be a good idea to upgrade Debian version as well while I'm at it, but I'm unsure whether that will break this further.

Any insight or suggestions is greatly appreciated, I've done a ton of research and I'm out of places to turn.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using an outdated version of [Django MSSQL](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io) database connector. According to its [change log](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#v1-8), starting with v1.8 the connector support MS SQL Server 2012 and later.

In order to confirm this, check the [DATABASES settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases) of your Django app, and see if it shows `'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado'` as the connection type. If so, 
`pip install django-mssql --upgrade` should fix your issue (though I haven't actually tested this).

---

**EDIT:** OK, so based on additional info from your comment (`'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc'` in the DATABASES settings), it looks like you're actually using [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) as the database connector. This driver seems to be quite Django-version dependent. Let's first find out which version is in use:

```
pip show django-pyodbc-azure
```

The version you install should be the same as the Django version. If using Django 1.8, and if the django-pyodbc-azure version shows less than that, try installing the correct version:

```
pip install "django-pyodbc-azure<1.9"
```

Comment: It says 'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc'   -Is this the correct one?

Comment: I havent been able to figure out what version of sql_server.pyodbc it is either